# System no longer mounts fs at specified mountpoint, but makes its own mountpoint

Tags: mount, lubuntu

Linux q-1 5.13.0-48-generic #54~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 2 23:37:17 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I use two external file systems on my laptop mounted thus:

```
~ $ ls -l /media/q
28
drwxrwxrwx 50 q sambashare 12288 Jun 30 17:30 256GB/
drwxr-xr-x  2 q q           4096 Jul  1 12:00 HDD1/
drwxr-xr-x 25 q q          12288 Jun 30 18:12 HDD11/
```

HDD1 is the proper mountpoint, but the last two days the system refuses to use it, and generates HDD11 instead.
I think, as HDD1 is dated at the time I started the system, that it no longer carries any internal record of /media/q/HDD1, whereas it shows the date of last usage for HDD11.
But HDD1 does exist, and I can and have written files to it on June 30 too, but the system is behaving as if it creates HDD1 for the very first time each time I boot up.

I've tried removing both HDD1 and HDD11 while the system is running, then reinserting the device, and it gets mounted on HDD11, even when I explicitly recreate HDD1 before reinserting the device.

Comment: You've not provided any release details; but your kernel indicates you're on a release that is about to go EOL, or you're behind on security fixes & upgrades; as installed systems/users using the 5.13 kernel should have migrated to 5.15 so I'd check your release & upgrade asap.  Providing your release allows us know better understand your software stack.  Telling us how you mount it may also help; I'd expect it to mount exactly where you specify if you used the system's *file-system table* (ie. `/etc/fstab`) thus defining location.. How were you mounting? ie. be specific

Comment: The `/media` tree is managed by the automounter, and is not designed for use by anybody else. Create a directory for the mountpoint (`sudo mkdir -p /mnt/HDD11`) and mount it there. Read `man blkid mount fstab`.

Comment: Sorry, Lubuntu 20.04 is the release, and it certainly is behind on updates, but that is not the problem, I use 2 laptops with 20.04 and the other still works fine.  I do not mount these devices, they are plug and play and the system automounts them, so there are no entries  for them in /etc/fstab. All I did with them, 2 years ago, was to give them labels and create the mountpoints for those labels. I didn't create entries for them in /etc/fstab because I mostly, but not always, use them, and I think fstab is for built-in fs, ie always to be mounted.

Comment: I suggest reading the manual page (`man fstab`) where you'll note `noauto`, `user` (to allow users to mount without `sudo`) and other options that prevent automatic mounting or allow easy later mounting.  The options in *fstab* dictate how the drive is mounted during system operation & dictate an always known device for system, or user-prompted during-operation mounts (if they occur). Something has likely changed on the drive/devices thus they're being treated as a secondary HDD11 (which may have been failure to `umount` first or other I cannot say) & use of *fstab* will prevent this.

Comment: I appreciate your help but I think we are working at cross-purposes here. I wish to recover what I had, the same distro, Lubuntu 20.04 on 2 laptops, that each would automount 2 detachable fs devices on their same expected mountpoints. One laptop continues to operate as expected, the other does not. If the change had occurred in the detachable fs, both laptops would behave the same. That the change has occurred on only one machine indicates some change has occurred in the OS on that machine only. What I'm really asking is; what would cause linux to behave this way?

Comment: If whilst a drive was mounted, it was pulled out & re-attached without OS knowledge; you risk having a new name on that device, but not others. If it was ejected from one device, changed on other then returned without proper mounts, the device where the change occurred will not have changed mounting (as it knew about the change it made so considers it normal). Occurring on a single machine as your last comment describes can cause it thru user error - failure to cleanly dismount/mount... Using *fstab* will prevent this user-created behavior; we've all accidentally pulled a USB cable out too ear

Comment: Aah, serendipity, just gotta love it. I entered the item in fstab, mounted perfectly. Turned system off, removed item and rebooted. As expected the boot hung waiting on the device. Inserted it, boot completed, but item not mounted. Removed and reinserted device, automounted properly with no more of that HDD11 nonsense. So I'm saved the trouble of installing new release. I take your point about usb sticks, but the device in question is a micro SD card. But certainly something happened with it. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite so serendipitous. Turns out that any /etc/fstab entry for a fs dominates the automount process, but when I removed the fstab entry so that booting wouldn't hang up if the fs was not present, then automount went back to its bad old ways with HDD11 again. I needed the fstab entry, but modified so that mount would ignore the fs if missing, which is given by the 'nofail' option, thus, in /etc/fstab

```
# LABEL=HDD1  UUID=0328f14c-7f13-444e-bbca-b2f9565d64fb TYPE=ext4
LABEL=HDD1     /media/q/HDD1    ext4    defaults,nofail   0 2
```

blkid /dev/sd? provides the info shown in the comment line, fdisk -l provides the actual value for /dev/sd?.  Both require sudo.